# Ag-Grid clipboard in community version

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I was working on a requirement where we have to copy multiple rows from Excel and paste in the ag-grid.
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/clipboard/
I see that this is a feature of Enterprise version.
I was just wondering if something similar to that can be implemented in the community version of the grid.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately not available. clpboard package comes via npm [(https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ag-grid-enterprise/clipboard)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ag-grid-enterprise/clipboard). The ag-grid-enterprise package, on the other hand, passes the LicenseManager control and adds them into Beans and makes them available.

you can send a mail to info@ag-grid.com and request a temporary license key and try it for 1 month.